# NullPointerException in Custom Dstinct Mapper

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

i am using hazelcast 3.6.1 and implementing distinct aggregate functionality using custom mapreduce to get solr facet kind of results.

```
public class DistinctMapper implements Mapper<String, Employee, String, Long>{

    private transient SimpleEntry<String, Employee> entry = new SimpleEntry<String, Employee>();

    private static final Long ONE = Long.valueOf(1L);

    private Supplier<String, Employee, String> supplier;

    public DistinctMapper(Supplier<String, Employee, String> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public void map(String key, Employee value, Context<String, Long> context) {
        System.out.println("Object "+ entry + " and key "+key);
        entry.setKey(key);
        entry.setValue(value);
        String fieldValue = (String) supplier.apply(entry);
        //getValue(value, fieldName);
        if (null != fieldValue){
            context.emit(fieldValue, ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

and mapper is failing with NullPointerException. and sysout statement says entry object is null.

SimpleEntry : https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.7-EA/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/mapreduce/aggregation/impl/SimpleEntry.java

Can you point me the issue in the above code ? Thanks.

Comment: is there any advantage of transient in mapper code in hazelcast ?

Answer (score 1):

`entry` field is transient. This means that it is not serialized, so when `DistinctMapper`object is deserialized on hazecalst node, it's value is null. 
Removing the transient will solve the `NullPointerException`.

On the side note: 
Why do you need this entry field? It doesn't seem to have any use.

Comment: I removed transient and worked. entry field required to apply the Supplier.  i see transient in hazelcast DistinctValueMapper  DistinctValuesAggregation.java code itself. so voiding serialization would save something. is there reason to use transient

Comment: @AnilDasari There are several reasons to use transient, I invite you to read about Java Serialization for details: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/767/serialization#t=201608040938312782102. But to answer your question about `DistinctValueMapper`, it doesn't use default java serialization, but a custom one, as can be seen in `AggregationsDataSerializerHook`. A `DistinctValueMapper` is created using `new` operator instead of `readObject` method, therefor `entry` field is initiated properly.